# How to read multiple .xlsx and generate multimple data frames in R?

Tags: r, excel

I want to read three different files in xlsx and save them in three different dataframes called excel1, excel2 and excel3. How can I do that? I think it should be something like this:

```
files = list.files(pattern='[.]xlsx') #There are three files.

for (i in 1:files){
    "excel" + i =read.xlsx(files[i])
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use a list instead of creating 3 variables in the current workspace:

```
dfList <- list()
for (i in 1:files){
    dfList[[paste0("excel",i)]] <- read.xlsx(files[i])
}
```

Then you can access to them in this way :

```
dfList$excel1
dfList$excel2
dfList$excel3
```

or :

```
dfList[[1]]
dfList[[2]]
dfList[[3]]
```

But, if you really really want to create new variables, you can use [`assign`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html) function :

```
for (i in 1:files){
    assign(paste0("excel",i), read.xlsx(files[i]))
}
# now excel1, excel2, excel3 variables exist...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `plyr` also and it's a good practice to mention the environment in which you want to create the variable:

```
library(plyr)
l_ply(1:length(files), function(i) assign(paste0('excel',i),read.xlsx(files[i]), envir=globalenv()))
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone tries to use this code, this parameters are really helpful:

```
  library(xlsx)

  files = list.files(pattern='[.]xlsx')
  dfList <- list()

  for (i in 1:length(files)){
      dfList[[paste0("excel",i)]] <- read.xlsx(files[i],header=T,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,sheetIndex = 1)
  }
```